# Is it possible to build `git` such that the install directory and the deployment prefix is not the same?

Tags: git, autoconf

I am attempting to build `git` from source, and I would like `make install` to put the binaries into a directory called `dist` in my source directory, so I use the following `configure` line.

```
./configure --prefix=`pwd`/dist
```

Unfortunately, this also causes the build output to assume that this is the final install location for `git`, and therefore hardcode the path into various scripts and binaries such as `libexec/git-core/git-difftool`.

Is there a way to specify during either `configure` or `make` that I want a different path for actual deployment, such as `/usr/bin/local`, but still have `make install` go into the directory `pwd`/dist?

Comment: Rename existing /usr/bin/local/ to /usr/bin/local.temp, symlink /usr/bin/local to /dist, configure --prefix=/usr/bin/local, make install, rm symlink, restore dir name?

Comment: That is the trivial workaround but it does not address the root of the question.

Comment: Heh yeah, that's why I commented instead of answered. :)

Comment: For convenience of deployment to android, but the question should be taken at face value. As the first comment suggested,  the base problem is not hard to work around.

Comment: Note that a valid answer might be in the negative as long as there is convincing evidence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this question has been unanswered for a few days, I [emailed the git developers](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/281782), and received the following answer, indicating that I should set `prefix` to the actual install path, and use the `DESTDIR` environmental variable to control where `make install` puts files.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
DESTDIR=$(PWD)/dist make install
```

Thus, the deployment prefix should be set with `--prefix` during `./configure` while the install destination should be specified by `DESTDIR`.

Update: I have tested this solution and confirmed that it works correctly.

Comment: For completeness, this is the link to your mailing list post: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/281782

Comment: @sschuberth, Thanks for the link! I have incorporated it into the answer.

Comment: Didn't work for me. The only thing that works for the prefix is via `./configure`, but then `install` fail.s

Comment: It may be worth reaching out to the Git developers again and see if things have changed since 2015.